# Расшифровка json

Tags: json, php

Есть вот такая строка полученная из json

```
\u0421\u041f\u0410\u0421\u0418\u0411\u041e \u0421\u041b\u0423\u0416\u0418\u0412\u042b\u0419
```

Расшифровывал через плагин в NOTEPAD++ HTML TAG

Но как можно расшифровать это... Через php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Через php -

```
json_decode($str);
```

Если просто прочитать, я использую http://json.parser.online.fr

Comment: Дык да делаю именно так, но всё равно  текст вот такой
\u0421\u041f\u0410\u0421\u0418\u0411\u041e \u0421\u041b\u0423\u0416\u0418\u0412\u042b\u0419

Comment: Правда, шль?

    <?php
    print(json_decode('"\u0421\u041f\u0410\u0421\u0418\u0411\u041e \u0421\u041b\u0423\u0416\u0418\u0412\u042b\u0419"'));

Answer (score 0):

Такие вопросы не для StackOverflow!
Такое обычно используют компании по набору сотрудников в отдел кибербезопасности (мой знакомый проходил тоже самое)

Но прошло 5 лет и вот как это делается:
Расшифровано тут:
[phpencoder](http://ddecode.com/phpdecoder/)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ERROR: Nothing much to decode. If you are having issues, please email us at dcid@sucuri.net -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------